# Intuition behind salient numbers in number of h-cobordism classes of smooth homotopy n-spheres

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, integer-sequences

The Wikipedia article on [Exotic Sphere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_sphere) displays this sequence of numbers (see also OEIS [A001676](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_sphere) and the Milnor link therein) for the order of the classses as

$$1, \;1, \;1,\; 1,\; 1, \;1, \;28,\; 2,\; 8,\; 6,\; 992,\; 1,\; 3,\; 2,\; 16256, \;2,\; 16,\; 16,\; 523264,\; 24, \;8, \;4,\;...$$

with the numbers for the dimensions $4n+3$ greater than three sticking out like sore thumbs. It also juxtaposes the factors of the associated Kervaire-Milnor formula (described also enthusiastically by Mazur in "[Bernoulli numbers and the unity of mathematics](http://wstein.org/wiki/attachments/2008(2f)480a/Bernoulli.pdf)" by Barry Mazur, Secs. 4, 5, and 6).

[Edit (Jan. 5, 2021) An inspiring introductory talk on this topic was given by Michael Hopkins, "[Bernoulli numbers, homotopy groups, and Milnor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=qLA3BQDcgfk)" last Feb.]

[Edit (May 22, 2021) A survey article containing recent computations: "[Stable homotopy groups of spheres](https://www.pnas.org/content/117/40/24757)" Isaksen, Wang, and Xu.)

Why do these particular dimensions stand out? What is the ultimate source of this peculiarity?

([Further notes](http://tcjpn.wordpress.com/2015/10/04/the-kervaire-milnor-formula/) are available at my website, including references by experts on connections to the Bernoulli numbers--Kervaire and Milnor.)

Comment: Stated more simply, those are the orientation-preserving diffeomorphism classes of homotopy spheres.   As to why the numbers crop up, wouldn't the best resource be Kervaire-Milnor?  IMO trying to view this through the lens of number theory isn't very fruitful.  Numbers are part of the descriptive language but that doesn't mean they're really orchestrating the result.

Comment: @TomCopeland Have you watched any videos of lectures related to the Kervaire invariant one conjecture? Specifically, this one by Mark Behrens:
http://www.ima.umn.edu/videos/?id=1789

Comment: Really? I think it is not uncommon. Mathematics is a large field with many people in it doing different things.

Comment: I did not interpret Ryan's comments that way exactly. I saw them more as an attempt to flesh out the question. Just asking "why do these two things show up?" can frequently be improved upon as a question, which is what your question looks like at first glance.

Comment: I am not aware of the History, but I might call your question "too discussiony" and I don't know that I would mean it in an insulting way.

Comment: I remember Richard Stanley once posed something like the following problem: "Fill in the missing number: 1, 1, 1, _, 1, 1, 1, ..." The answer is $\infty$, because this is the sequence of the number of differential structures on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: @TomCopeland: I guess my point was that viewing these results in terms of sequences of numbers might not be so useful...

Comment: Objections above notwithstanding, see Ravi Vakil's Abel lecture about "nature trying to tell us something": "Algebraic geometry and the ongoing unification of mathematics" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vOboYNh_5is&t=1016s // Michael Hopkins lecture is in the same spirit. Comments above smack of demonstrable number aversion related to an overreactive, overly sensitive ambiguity aversion. And there are many interesting responses to Stanley's 'problem'.

Comment: Another example of the empirical approach: "Langlands Program and Unification" by Frenkel https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b8e_HMEwKIY&t=1070s

Comment: Other examples of productively following the scent of a number sequence are apparent in the book Symmetry and the Monster by Ronan.

Comment: Straw-man arguments (in particular, those involving 'low entropy' number sequences with one outlier point allowed and no criteria for interpolation) don't impress me as apparently it does others.